# Windows Phone 7.5 App download

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

Do I need active phone connection to download app from the Windows Market Place?

When I try to install the App from MarKet Place, I receive a error

> we tried sending a download request to your phone but we did not reeive a response.

I gave continue to send the email on re-install.

Received re-install email, clicked on the link, and it goes back to same screen and the same error occurs again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it sends a special SMS to the phone to start the download. You can instead download using the Marketplace app on the phone.